# como hago para que me retorne 5 numero aleatorio en SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Este es mi codigo: el codigo me devuelve una numero aleatorio todo bien pero al poner TOP  no me genera 5 filas siempre me genera una fila

```
declare @NumeroDesde int = 00 ;
declare @NumeroHasta int = 99 ;
SELECT  top 5 ROUND(((@NumeroHasta - @NumeroDesde) * RAND() + @NumeroDesde), 0)
```

Ayuda gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema tiene dos partes.

Una primera que es generar el número de filas que uno quiere, y una segunda, que los valores de esas filas sean aleatorios y diferentes entre ellos.

Para la primera parte, puedes utilizar la función [getNums](https://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt) de Itzik Ben-Gan

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- © Itzik Ben-Gan, SolidQ
-- For more, see 5-day Advanced T-SQL Course:
-- http://tsql.solidq.com/t-sql-courses/
----------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
             FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO
```

La misma te retorna la lista de números entre el rango suministrado como parámetros. En el caso que nos ocupa sería un 1 y un 5. Y retorna 1,2,3,4,5.

Y la segunda parte es obtener estos aleatorios.

Para esto puedes utilizar las funciones [newid()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que nos retorna un valor uniqueidentifier. La función [checksum()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que nos devolverá un int del parámetro suministrado. Y [abs()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que nos retornará el valor absoluto positivo. El [módulo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 100 nos retornará el resto de dividir el numero entre 100 por tanto será un número entre 0 y 99, y no hace falta definir las variables.

```
  SELECT abs(checksum(newid())%100)
  FROM GetNums(1,5) fn
```

[image: Salida]

[Números aleatorios en un rango](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/20/numeros-aleatorios-entre-un-rango-n-m/)